Exclusions and Inclusion in syslog-ng
I have 2 syslog filter that I want to merge together but not getting the right syntax
{netmask(192.168.0.1/32) or netmask(192.16.0.5/32);};

and
{not(match("sso_login") or match("fake-domain.com"));};

This sometimes breaks the log line or mismatch when there are multiple filters in same syslog-ng.conf file. So I am trying to use both the filters in one line. Something like
{(netmask(192.168.0.1/32) or netmask(192.16.0.5/32)) and (not(match("sso_login") or match("fake-domain.com")));};

Please help with the correct syntax for it
